# Sharing Wifi-internet access via bluetooth

Tags: windows, linux, android, connection-sharing

I'm on an extremely strict wireless network, which locks down one machine to one account. [Hotel wifi] Is there a way that I can share the Wifi connection with my android tablet via bluetooth?

Windows and Linux solutions are prefered.

The machine connecting to WIFI will be the Laptop/[Windows|Linux] machine.

Comment: You might want to have a look at some of the [questions tagged 'bluetooth-tethering' over at the Android Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-tethering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you want ICS or [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing). Pair the devices (your tablet and your Windows/Linux machine) first than activate ICS.

For Linux, there's several different ways to do this. You'd basically be activating routing on Linux. You could do this via ipforward or a set application. But if you're asking this question, I'd recommend you stick with Windows and ICS.

Comment: The ICS link is now stale. It now has a title but no content.