# Share internet connection from windows to android via bluetooth

Tags: windows, android, bluetooth, connection-sharing

I have an internet connection via ppoe, which works on my pc. My pc is connected to the router via wifi, and I don't think I have a second wifi card (and I don't have an ethernet cable - so I can't use my pc as a router).

I would like to connect to the internet with my non-rooted Android. I saw some instructions about sharing internet connection (for example [Sharing Wifi-internet access via bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/491352/sharing-wifi-internet-access-via-bluetooth) ),but  I have paired the computer and the phone, shared the ppoe connection and internet still doesn't work on my phone. Is there something missing?

Comment: Why do you want to use Bluetooth instead of regular Wi-Fi connection to the router?

Comment: I can connect to the router, but not to internet, because i cannot set up a ppoe connection with an un-rooted android

Comment: See also: [Sharing a PC Internet to a Android phone via Bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/782815)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a second Wi-Fi card to be able to share an Internet connection, most modern Wi-Fi chips are able to run in both client and access point modes simultaneously, see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx). The needed commands to set up and enable the Wireless Hosted Network are:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=YourNetworkName key=YourPassword
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

This is a solution for Windows 7 and above. For Windows XP there is [Virtual Wi-Fi from Microsoft Research](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/virtualwifi/), although it's a bit limited in that you can't use it with WPA-encrypted connections, only WEP is supported.